# Baseline shifts for block-level element when no content inside

Tags: html, css

I'm working through a CSS problem at http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-jNuXw/0/1?curriculum_id=50579fb998b470000202dc8b (actually, just helping a friend learn HTML/CSS) and came across a curious issue.  If you erase the content in any of the `<p>` tags within a `<div>`, the div shifts upward.  For example, delete the word 'Mom' without deleting the `<p>`.  As best as I can figure out, this is because the element is set to `vertical-align: baseline` and for some reason the baseline is changing.  I just can't figure out exactly why it's changing or what is causing it to change.

To be clear, I'm not asking for help to get the div's to align.  That's simply a matter of setting their vertical-align to 'top'.  I'm just trying to understand how the document flow is calculated.  The specific question is: why does the empty div shift upwards?

**DEMO**: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2DtTw/)

**UPDATE**: Here is a new jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/tonicboy/2DtTw/3/ which removes a lot of rules to boil the problem down to a simplified use case.  From this, we can see that when a `<p>` tag has text in it, the baseline of the parent `<div>` is set at the baseline of the text.  When you remove the text, the baseline of the parent `<div>` is set to the bottom of the  `<div>`.  Why is that?

HTML:

```
<div class="friend" id="best_friend"><p>Arthur</p></div>
<div class="friend"><p>Batmanuel</p></div>
<div class="friend"><p>Captain Liberty</p></div>
<div class="friend"><p>The City</p></div>
<div class="friend"><p>Justice</p></div>
<div class="family"><p></p></div>
<div class="family"><p>Dad</p></div>
<div class="family"><p>Bro</p></div>
<div class="family"><p>Sis</p></div>
<div class="family"><p>Rex</p></div>
<div class="enemy"><p>Baron Violent</p></div>
<div class="enemy"><p>The Breadmaster</p></div>
<div class="enemy"><p>The Deadly Nose</p></div>
<div class="enemy"><p>Dinosaur Neil</p></div>
<div class="enemy" id="archnemesis"><p>Chairface</p></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

div p {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 40px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.friend {
    border: 2px dashed green;
}

.family {
    border: 2px dashed blue;
}

.enemy {
    border: 2px dashed red;
}

#best_friend {
    border: 4px solid #00C957;
}

#archnemesis {
    border: 4px solid #cc0000;
}
```

Comment: Depends on the CSS being applied. Please post the HTML and CSS in your question.

Comment: I already did.  It's in the link above.

Comment: Please post the HTML and CSS **in your question**.

Comment: @TNguyen Include everything in your post or in a JSFiddle.  External links are against SO rules because they may not persist and therefore future readers will not benefit from this question.

Comment: All the exact HTML and CSS is available at the link.  If you don't want to help then that's ok, that's your prerogative.  But I'm not going to sit here and hand type in their whole CSS and HTML.

Comment: You do realise there is a thing called copy & paste?

Comment: Point taken.  When I have time I'll try to reproduce the problem in a jsFiddle.  But I know of no SO rule saying external links are illegal.

Comment: And what is the question? is the normal behavior of inline elements.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2DtTw/ there's your jsFiddle, took all of 1 minute

Comment: The exact HTML and CSS is available **at the moment** but if the external site changes then it is no longer available, and no one else can then benefit from your question.

Comment: Look, I get it already.  Give it a rest.  Sheesh, people here are 10x more interested in chewing people out for form violations than actually answering questions.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've mostly figured out the reason, after digging through W3C specs.  Here are three key items from the spec which may explain this behavior:

1. "**Line boxes that contain no text**, no preserved white space, no inline elements with non-zero margins, padding, or borders, and no other in-flow content (such as images, inline blocks or inline tables), and do not end with a preserved newline must be treated as zero-height line boxes for the purposes of determining the positions of any elements inside of them, and **must be treated as not existing** for any other purpose."

   - When you delete the text, the `<p>` element is no longer *in-flow*.
2. "The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box in the normal flow, **unless it has either no in-flow line boxes** or if its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', **in which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge**."

   - Because there are no *in-flow* elements within the parent div, the baseline becomes the bottom margin.
3. Because the div's are set to `display: inline-block`, their default vertical alignment is 'baseline'
4. Because the other div's have *in-flow* elements (the `<p>` tags), their baseline is set to the text baseline.

**And that is why the empty box's bottom margin aligns with the baseline of the `<p>` tags in the other div's.**

Comment: Well i don't think point 1 is valid. As `The rectangular area that contains the boxes that form a line is called a line box.`, your `<p>` actually does contain height and margin. The `<p>` as you can see in the inspector mode is still in-flow. besides : `An element is called out of flow if it is floated, absolutely positioned, or is the root element.`
 
Also point 4, your shifted `<div>` does have a in-flow element, it indeed doesn't hasn't a baseline.

Answer (score 1):

The baseline of the element is shifting because the text inside the `<p>` determs the baseline height:

> In an inline formatting context, boxes are laid out horizontally, one
>   after the other, beginning at the top of a containing block.
>   Horizontal margins, borders, and padding are respected between these
>   boxes. The boxes may be aligned vertically in different ways: their
>   bottoms or tops may be aligned, **or the baselines of text within them**
>   may be aligned.

source: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting

> The height of each inline-level box in the line box is calculated. For
>   replaced elements, inline-block elements, and inline-table elements,
>   this is the height of their margin box; for inline boxes, this is
>   their 'line-height'.

source: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height

> CSS assumes that every font has font metrics that specify a
>   characteristic height above the baseline and a depth below it. In this
>   section we use A to mean that height (for a given font at a given
>   size) and D the depth. We also define AD = A + D, the distance from
>   the top to the bottom.

source: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-box-height

So with this block being a `inline-block` and baseline is calculted based on the `line-height` which is calcuted by different font types. Because this `<p>` has no font/text the baseline will not be positioned.

place all the `line-height: 0;` and you will see that the one with no text/font doesn't react like the other does:

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2DtTw/5/)**

**So why are the other two elemets shifting that have text in them?**

Well it's because the text excist of two lines of text. The margin of the text is bigger and uses more space, thus the baseline is pushed further

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer but this is pretty much what I had already answered.  Because the `<p>` has no text, its baseline is not positioned.

Comment: Responded. I wasn't sure if you were 100% sure about your answer, so my bad if you are.

Comment: No, you have some useful information in there.  All I'm saying is that we essentially said the same thing.  The important point is that, when there is no text in the p, it causes the baseline of the square to move to the bottom margin.  Thanks.

Comment: Yea that's right :) Great interesting question! Glad i could 'help'.